# Efficient 3D mesh topology for CFD simulation of turbine blade

Tags: airflow, cfd, wind-power, meshing, wind-tunnels

I´m developing a tool to generate an [openFoam](http://www.openfoam.com/) wind tunnel case of a wind turbine.  I already have the blade geometry constructed, but I'm really new to CFD and parametric meshing.  I found some articles where they mention a C topology to mesh the airfoil and also some software ([bladedesigner](http://bladedesigner.sourceforge.net/)) that mentions a topology named O10H, but none of these has a reference about how to implement these topologies and if there are others.  They also do not specify what the best use cases for each one.

Can someone help me to get started making an efficient mesh for my tool?

**EDIT:** At the end I want to have a domain like the picture below, with other blade orientation, but first I need to define the mesh topology around the blade.

[image]

**My example Blade:**

[image]

Some of the mesh topologies that I found:

**Bladedesigner O10H topology**

[image: Bladedesigner O10H]

**Various C topologies**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to have different blocks? Or do you have to mesh the whole domain with one block?

Comment: @rul30 at the end I want to have a domain line [this](http://www.upsara.com/images/0t4h_captu33r45re.jpg) , but now I'm looking of the correct mesh topology for the blade and the tips of how to split this topology into domains

Comment: @rul30 I edit my question with my first blade example and others C topologies that I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modeled a vertical axis turbine back in 2010 in a two dimensional rotating reference frame in OpenFOAM with good results. I am not up to date with the new tools available, but you want to make sure that your geometry is in fact rotating according to the model (perhaps your periodic boundaries are handling this for you).

I used gmsh (http://geuz.org/gmsh/) for my mesh generation. You want to make sure your boundary layer on the blade surface is hexahedral and the remaining volume can be filled with tetrahedrals as they are very forgiving of complex geometery.

I would highly recommend reposing your question on cfd-online. Lots of experts on there with specific OpenFOAM experience.
http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but my question is mainly directed to the selection of the mesh topology for the blade. What criteria should be followed to pick between the O, C and H topologys,  or just any works well

Comment: I think any of them will work well as they are all composed of hexahedrals. Just select the one that best fits your geometery. I used O on all of mine because I had a spline based trailing edge, not a theoretical trailing edge point/line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using third party software for meshing like gmsh, gambit or fluent where you can import your geometry, edit it, define the topology and get the mesh.
Gmesh is free while the rest are not.
You might be able to find many tutorials on meshing in these softwares on youtube